# Multiple django-tenants using only one domain

Tags: python, django, django-models, middleware, django-tenants

I have a Django application running, right now we have different schemas into different subdomains (ex: schema 1: subdomain1.domain.com, schema 2: subdomain2.domain.com). I need to change this for different schemas into one domain.

Problems:

1. Authentication: today the auth is made in TENANT_APPS, but I think that need to change, for the auth works.
2. Maintaining the session: I tried some solutions, but the times I managed to authenticate the user, the session was not maintained or was not created, so I could not navigate through the application. Can somebody help me?

I've tried some of the issues in django-tenants (https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants)

EDIT: I found the solution at https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants/issues/624